# java JFrame setContentPanel and then JPanel disappear

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class ReadPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public ReadPanel(){
        super();
        setBackground(new Color(255, 182, 193));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GroupLayout gl_panel_main = new GroupLayout(this);
        gl_panel_main.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel_main.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_main.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 402, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_panel_main.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel_main.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_main.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
        setLayout(gl_panel_main);
    }
    public void setNews(String news){
        textArea.setText(news);
    }
    public String getNews(){
        return textArea.getText();
    }
    //another complex method here...
}

public class SetContentPanelFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private ReadPanel panel_main;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SetContentPanelFrame frame = new SetContentPanelFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void goFullReadMode(){
        /*ReadPanel copy = new ReadPanel();
        copy.setNews(panel_main.getNews());
        copy.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                exitFullReadMode();
            }
        });
        //Set another property here...
        this.setContentPane(copy);*/

        this.setContentPane(panel_main);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();
    }
    public void exitFullReadMode(){
        this.setContentPane(contentPane);
        //contentPane.add(panel_main);
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SetContentPanelFrame() {
        setTitle("Set Content Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 741, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel_menu = new JPanel();
        panel_menu.setBackground(new Color(240, 248, 255));

        JPanel panel_ads = new JPanel();
        panel_ads.setBackground(new Color(255, 239, 213));

        panel_main = new ReadPanel();
        panel_main.setNews("This is a news\r\n1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
                + "This is a news\r\n2\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
                + "This is a news\r\n3\r\n\r\n\r\n"
                + "This is a news\r\n4");
        panel_main.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                exitFullReadMode();
            }
        });

        JButton btnViewFull = new JButton("View full");
        btnViewFull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                goFullReadMode();
            }
        });
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(panel_menu, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(btnViewFull)
                            .addContainerGap())
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(panel_main, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 422, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(panel_ads, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnViewFull)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(panel_main, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 222, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel_ads, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 222, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel_menu, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 222, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        panel_ads.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lblAds = new JLabel("Ads...");
        lblAds.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel_ads.add(lblAds, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_menu.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lblMenu = new JLabel("Menu");
        lblMenu.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        panel_menu.add(lblMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}
```

I want to switch between two JPanel (**contentPane** and **panel_main**) using *setContentPane* method.

There are 2 important method: *goFullReadMode*() and *exitFullReadMode*().

When I run this program, the *goFullReadMode*() do correctly, but when switch back to default panel (click the pink area outside the text), the middle panel (**panel_main**) is disappear. Why it doesn't display again?
[image]

I think that it has been moved to somewhere, so in *exitFullReadMode* method, I try:

```
contentPane.add(panel_main);
```

But it doesn't display in correct position because the container has a GroupLayout, and regoup all component is not a good idea.

An afternate solution is make a copy of **panel_main** and *setContentPane* to this copy, but we need to copy all content(data, sub-component, ...) to this copy object (like the comment in goFullReadMode method). So it is not easy way to do.

Is there any solution that does not need make a copy of the panel and still keep it when we switch back to default view?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using only one reference to the `panel_main` by the time you call `this.setContentPane(panel_main2);` it will then remove it self from the `contentPane` panel and add itself to the `Frame` as its main `Panel` thus you can not see it in your `contentPane` panel upon exiting the fullscreen.

**solution:**

since you cant resize it back to its state, you can create 2 instance of `ReadPanel` one for the `contentPane` and one for the fullscreen

```
    panel_main = new ReadPanel();
    panel_main2 = new ReadPanel();
    panel_main.setNews("This is a news\r\n1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n2\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n3\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n4");

    panel_main2.setNews("This is a news\r\n1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n2\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n3\r\n\r\n\r\n"
            + "This is a news\r\n4");
    panel_main2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            exitFullReadMode();
        }
```

For going **fullScreen**

```
 public void goFullReadMode(){
    this.setContentPane(panel_main2);
    this.repaint();
    this.revalidate();
}
```

Now when you update the text of the `panel_main` you must update the `panel_main2` as well.